# "Print" & "Cancel" disappeared from Printer Options in UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityviewcontroller

[image: Printer options with no visible buttons]

The buttons are still there and function fine, however as you can see they are completely invisible. Adjusting font colors and navigation bar colors had no effect. I have been trying to resolve this for months and despite reading Apple's documentation, I am unable to even see where you would change what I assumed to be a system wide function.

[image: The plot thickens]

So to help narrow down this issue I created a simple navigation controller with a print button. If I put these both on the Login storyboard (the first storyboard) it works perfectly fine. If I put it on Main.storyboard (the second storyboard) it doesn't work.

If I change my project settings to make Main.storyboard the first storyboard it works. Leading me to believe the issue is in my FirstViewController.

Comment: are you anywhere used `tintColor` of `UIBarButtonItem` in your app.

Comment: Thank you this led me to finding the issue. For whatever reason someone set the tint alpha to 0 in the view and for some reason this was passed on throughout the app.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the color of the print and cancel button

```
UIBarButtonItem.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UIToolbar.self]).tintColor = UIColor.green
```

Comment: This was not inherently the problem as I had set the tint on all my other views to various colors, and such colors worked on everything except print. Apparently changing the first view and only the first view seemed to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

After narrowing down the problem to the first view controller I discovered the tint was set to Clear Color (ie Alpha is 0). Fixing this resolved the problem in the rest of the app. I am surprised a setting in a view can propogate to the rest of the app and overwrite all of the other views in the process. Perhaps apple set the first view to determine the colors for system pop ups etc.